# Giving rw permissions for everyone on USB device

Tags: linux, usb, permissions

I just bought a Zigbee USB device, and I plugged it into my server, but I can't start the relevant containers, because they have no permission to read/write on the device. I figured that adding the user to the `dialout` group (which has rw permissions on that device) wouldn't be smart, because it could be able to control other devices too.

Is there any security risk with adding global rw permissions on my zigbee usb device?

Comment: You can change its ownership instead, or make use of ACL.

Comment: The proper way of doing this in Linux is to create a group and assign your users to that group, then *write an `udev` rule* which will target this specific device and assign `rw` on the device nodes to that group. The `dialout` thing works the same way, just it targets the whole device *class*, not a single device.